# Windows 7 remote ODBC connection to Sybase 11

Tags: sql, windows-7, sybase

I'm using windows7 32bit, and connection to remote sybase databse using odbc
the connection goes fine, but when I'm retrieving arabic data I get unreadable characters

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

By "Sybase 11", are you talking about Sybase SQL Anywhere 11? AFAIK, Sybase ASE doesn't have a version 11 so I'm guessing here.

Make sure the character set you are using to connect to the database matches the character set the data is stored in. Try `select db_property('charset')`, which will tell you the character set. Then disconnect and reconnect using the `charset` connection parameter, [documented here](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbadmin/charset-conparm.html).